# How to synchronize two tables of PostgreSQL from tow different servers?

Tags: postgresql, synchronization

I am stuck in a scenario. where i am having single PostgreSQL on server_1. According to my app scenario, i have too much insertion in my DB like 500-2000 per second, due to which my database becomes too much slow down and most of time it did not respond to my other API'S. Now i have purchased another server and installed PostgreSQL on it. i want that, i will put all insertion queries on this newly added PostgreSQL server and older PostgreSQL will only respond to my other API'S.
now i just want to ask that, how can i synchronize both the servers. i want to synchronize them after each 12 hour in my case. is there anything in PostgreSQL which help me to achieve this? any suggestions or help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: look for postgres replication

Comment: replication as it is will not work for my solution. i want to synchronize at a specif time